# How do I retrieve Subject or Issuer Distinguished Name from a certificate with Apple Security framework?

Tags: c, objective-c, macos, security, certificate

I wanted to use the `SecCertificateCopyValues` function but could not find the correct certificate OID.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/certificates/certificate_oids?language=objc

Should I have used some other function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use `SecCertificateCopyValues`. In this returned dictionary, search for `kSecOIDX509V1IssuerName` from the Apple documentation link you mentioned. In the documentation of [SecCertificateCopyValues](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1396051-seccertificatecopyvalues) there is mentioned, that

> Each entry in this dictionary is itself a dictionary with the keys described in  [Certificate Property Keys](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/certificates/certificate_property_keys).

So, for example, to get the common name of the issuer, you would:

- retrieve a dictionary for the key kSecOIDX509V1IssuerName
- from there get the value array with the key kSecPropertyKeyValue
- each array element itself is a dictionary
- e.g. for the common name you want to use the key kSecOIDCommonName

To create a distinguished name you can check for different keys.

If you have an OID, you can look at the corresponding constant in Apple's open source [certificate values](https://opensource.apple.com/source/libsecurity_keychain/libsecurity_keychain-55029/lib/CertificateValues.cpp) and add to the code to get the values you are interested in:

In code, this might look like this:

```
static CFStringRef createDistinguishedName(CFDictionaryRef certValues, CFStringRef key) {
    CFDictionaryRef dict = CFDictionaryGetValue(certValues, key);
    CFArrayRef values = CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kSecPropertyKeyValue);
    
    CFMutableStringRef dn = CFStringCreateMutableCopy(NULL, 0, CFSTR(""));
    
    CFStringRef keys[] = { kSecOIDCommonName, kSecOIDOrganizationName, kSecOIDOrganizationalUnitName, kSecOIDLocalityName, kSecOIDStateProvinceName, kSecOIDCountryName, kSecOIDSerialNumber, kSecOIDEmailAddress};
    CFStringRef txt[] = { CFSTR("CN"), CFSTR("O"), CFSTR("OU"), CFSTR("L"), CFSTR("S"), CFSTR("C"), CFSTR("SERIALNUMBER"), CFSTR("MAIL")};
    
    bool appendComa = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(values); i++) {
        CFDictionaryRef subDict = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(values, i);
        CFStringRef labelVal = CFDictionaryGetValue(subDict, kSecPropertyKeyLabel);
        
        for(int k = 0; k < sizeof(keys)/sizeof(keys[0]); k++) {
            if (kCFCompareEqualTo == CFStringCompare(labelVal, keys[k], 0)) {
                if (appendComa)
                    CFStringAppend(dn, CFSTR(", "));
                CFStringAppend(dn, txt[k]);
                CFStringAppend(dn, CFSTR("="));
                CFStringAppend(dn, CFDictionaryGetValue(subDict, kSecPropertyKeyValue));
                appendComa = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return dn;
}
```

It can be called like this:

```
void printDN(CFDataRef certData) {
    SecCertificateRef certRef = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, certData);
    CFDictionaryRef certValues = SecCertificateCopyValues(certRef, nil, nil);
    CFStringRef dn = createDistinguishedName(certValues, kSecOIDX509V1IssuerName);
    CFShow(dn);
    CFRelease(dn);
    CFRelease(certValues);
    CFRelease(certRef);
}
```

A sample certificate from [here](http://fm4dd.com/openssl/certexamples.htm) would result in the following string:

```
C=JP, S=Tokyo, L=Chuo-ku, O=Frank4DD, OU=WebCert Support, CN=Frank4DD Web CA, MAIL=support@frank4dd.com
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you very much.